# Can i build an NFT marketplace on 0x api

Tags: web3js, 0x

I just saw 0x.org today it looks interesting, i am working on an NFT marketplace on Polygon, your docs looks familiar as to what i am working on. so i want to know, if i can build an NFT marketplace on 0x.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Check out [swapsdk.xyz](https://swapsdk.xyz) for more information on how to get started building an NFT marketplace with 0x v4.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Here you can see an open source of a fully functional marketplace using ZRX contracts: https://github.com/DexKit/open-nft-marketplace